# update text on a page dynamically in response to event on another page in another window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies

I need to display the text "Welcome username" once a user is logged in, and show "login|register" link if not logged in or if cookie expired. However the text that I need to display is on index.php and the user authentication is done on checklogin.php.

I am not sure how to update the text on index.php (without refreshing /dynamically) as the event for authentication is performed on another page checklogin.php. Note that the login page opens in new page using '_blank'.

I am reproducing the code below:
thanks for your time.

index.php

```
<?php
if ($_COOKIE['cookieName']) { echo '<li>Welcome '. $_COOKIE['cookieName']; echo'|'; echo '<a href="logout.php" target="_blank">Logout</a> </li>';  }
else {echo' <li><a href="login.php" target="_blank" class="login">Login</a> | <a href="user_add.php" target="_blank" class="login">Register</a></li> '; }
?>
```

login.php

```
<form action="checklogin.php" method="post" name="form" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="username" value = '' />       
    <input type="password" name="password" value = '' />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Log me in." class="button"/>
```

checklogin.php

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table rows
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
$cookie_name ="$cookiename";
$cookie_expire ="300";
setcookie($cookie_name,$cookie_value,time() + (300),"/", $cookie_domain);
header("location:$successfulLogin_url");
}

else{
header("location:$failedLogin_url");
}
```

Comment: Assuming that `index.php` opens the window that contains `checklogin.php`, then you can use the `window.opener` property to access the main window. You haven't really said what event you want to handle, though.

Comment: On successful login, the cookie is set. I need to change the text on index.php at this moment. Also, the login page is in fact a new page '_blank' instead of a window.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you can only use `setInterval()` on `index.php` and [check cookie with javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). Once it's set, you can update html with user's login (remove login link and display welcome message).

However, I think it's not good practice to send user to second window with main site in the background. Modal dialog or even dynamically loaded login form on "Login" click would be better. But if you really need to do it this way, the interval background checking may be only way.